# hey guys i'm trying to get my website to jquery an html cause it has data in it. log and xmlrequest work, but it wont display in current page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

> current site that is open

```
<head>
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

> this script is suppose to grab the page and its infor using an xmlhttprequest

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "/user/answer.htm"
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'text';
        var x = xhr.responseText;
        var x = $(x, "#t").text();
```

> right here is where i cant figure it out i cant get the data i want from the file, however it still seems to be opening in the console and showing the current data so i think i'm just doing this jquery wrong

```
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log(xhr.response);
                    console.log(x);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
        $('#tag').html(x);
    });
//setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
</script>
<h1></h1>

<body>
    <p id="tag"></p>
</body>

</html>
<!--  -->
```

> page extracting data know as answers.htm

```
<html>
  <p id="t"><%=Tags.Tag1%></p>
</html>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell you the exact cause without seeing any debug information, however I can tell you that this line is wrong: `var x = $(x, "#t").text();`. The arguments in the jQuery object should be the other way around: `var x = $("#t", x).text();`. I'd also suggest not redefining `x`, but either creating a new variable, or setting a new value on it. If you still have issues, check the console for errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why not use `.load()` or `.ajax()` instead? It may be best to offer a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: put your `.html()` into the xhr.done

Comment: Since you are using jQuery there is no need for XMLHttpRequest.  you can check the docs for $.get in jquery documentation . e.g $.get( "/user/answer.htm").then(()=>{ /*do your work here.*/})

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tag").load("/user/answer.htm");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="tag"></p>
```

See More: https://api.jquery.com/load/

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched elements.

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when `textStatus` is "success" or "notmodified"), `.load()` sets the HTML contents of the matched elements to the returned data.

Comment: .load works the best what i need, thank you so much!